# Deleting elements of a class

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I'm making a recipe book in Python and have done so with a class with attributes

> `class.name` - name of recipe
>   `class.ing_count` - number of ingredients
>   `class.ings` - Python dictionary containing ingredient name, amount, and units on amount.

I'm trying to make it delete specific ingredients within a recipe but this isn't working. Any thoughts?

**Deleting Ingredients**

```
   searchrecipe = raw_input("Recipe to edit: )
            if edit_ing == 1:
                del_ing = raw_input("Ingredient to Delete: ")
                del_ing.title()
                #Search Ingredient list
                for recipe in TheBook:
                    if recipe.name == searchrecipe:
                        del recipe.ings[del_ing]
                        break
```

Comment: So your question is...? What's wrong? Why isn't it working? And can you give us a [mcve] of your class?

Comment: You're missing an quotation mark in your first line.

Comment: Also, like all `str` methods, `del_ing.title()` returns a new string, it doesn't mutate the existing one in place. You need to assign back to `del_ing` to make the change persist.

Comment: What you are calling "class attributes" appear to be "instance attributes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
del_ing.title()
```

does not modify del_ing. You need to bind the return value back to the variable

```
del_ing = del_ing.title()
```